# Unity - One method from a class not working at other classes but the others do

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so the thing is im trying to use a method called `SetPlayerMoney()`, declared in the `MoneyCounterController(see below)` and it doesn't work in a specific class, I better show you:

So, first, this is the `BuildingController` file:

```
public class BuildingController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BuildingControllerUtils buildingUtils;
    public MoneyCounterController moneyCounterController;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        buildingUtils = new BuildingControllerUtils(this, "Edificio", "InGame/Edificio1/");


        moneyCounterController = GameObject.Find("MoneyCounter").gameObject.GetComponent<MoneyCounterController>();

  //Here the method execute correctly
 moneyCounterController.SetPlayerMoney(25000);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        buildingUtils.UpgradeBuilding(moneyCounterController);
    }
}
```

The `MoneyCounterController` file is the class that manages all the display info about the player money, here's the code:

```
public class MoneyCounterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text MoneyCounterTxt;
    public int playerMoney;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {                       
        MoneyCounterTxt = GetComponent<Text>();
        playerMoney = 0;

  //Here it executes the method
        SetPlayerMoney(playerMoney);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.anyKeyDown)
        {
            playerMoney = playerMoney + 10;
            SetPlayerMoney(playerMoney);

            //Debug.Log("Se cambio el numero de dinero!");
        }
    }

    public void SetPlayerMoney(int playerMoneyParam)
    {
        MoneyCounterTxt.text = playerMoneyParam.ToString();
    }

    public int GetPlayerMoney()
    {
        return playerMoney;
    }
}
```

But it's at this time when the problems begins, when i call it at a utils class, it doesn't work the `SetPlayerMoney` method, BUT, the `GetPlayerMoney` method does.
Here's the code:

```
public class BuildingControllerUtils
{       

    // Use this for initialization
    public BuildingControllerUtils(MonoBehaviour behaviour, String assetBuildingName, String spritePath)
    {       

    }

    public void UpgradeBuilding(MoneyCounterController moneyCounterController)
    {                   
        int playerMoney = moneyCounterController.GetPlayerMoney();

  //THE METHOD HERE DOESN'T WORK
 moneyCounterController.SetPlayerMoney(25000);

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I've simplified the Utils class for more focus on the method which doesn't work.

Comment: Can you make a simple reproducible example?

Comment: @LudovicFeltz I've simplified the code for better reproduction if needed

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, can you be more specific? A null reference? Nothing happens? If nothing happens, have you tried attaching a debugger?

Comment: Do you have an error? How is `moneyCounterController`'s instance created? Did you attached `MoneyCounterController` as a Component in an GameObject of your scene?

Comment: @RyanSingh No null references, no compiler or syntax errors, i've used the debugger and it appears like the method worked, but at the run time it's just like nothing happens

Comment: How would you know if it worked if on both occasions you're setting the text to be 25000? If it seems like it works, try it with another number?

Comment: @LudovicFeltz it's all attached and correctly instantiated, at least at the `BuildingController` class, because there the methods works fine. At the `BuildingControllerUtils` class i pass the instance as a parameter and it's not null because i can use the other method :/

Comment: @RyanSingh because at the run time i got a script that sets the money to 0 for see if anything changes, in fact, it's at the `MoneyCounterController ` class, in the `Start()` method

Comment: I agree. But ```Start()``` on the ```MoneyCounterController``` will set the value to 0 once and never again as ```Start()``` is only called once as you're passing the same reference of the script. So the ```BuildingController``` will set it to 25000 and then the ```BuildingControllerUtils``` will set it to 25000 again when you press the mouse. Unless you're setting the value to 0 elsewhere?

Comment: @RyanSingh I set the value to the Player money - the upgrade price in other method, it doesn't work neither

Comment: Stick a `Debug.Log()` into `SetPlayerMoney` to ensure it's being called and remove `MoneyCounterTxt = GetComponent<Text>();` from `MoneyCounterController`.

Comment: @Lece I did it, if i remove the `MoneyCounterTxt = GetComponent<Text>();` the text doesn't update. And yes, the method it's being called

Comment: `MoneyCounterTxt` is already of type `Text` so `GetComponent` is not required. See [UI.Text](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text-text.html)

Comment: @Lece, ```MoneyCounterTxt``` is being assigned for the first time here. By removing it, there is no reference. I am assuming they are not assigning it in the editor.

Comment: OK, so there's no issue with output (as I'd suspected), and the function is working @alex55132 which you've verified with a log?

Comment: It's working at the `BuildingController` class but not at the `BuildingControllerUtils ` class @Lece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution for this problem, it was the `Update()` method at  `MoneyCounterController.cs` class, when i pressed any key (`Input.GetKeyDown()`) it was updating the money quicker than any script could modify. So the final code would look like this:

```
// Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            playerMoney = playerMoney + 10;
            SetPlayerMoney(playerMoney);

            //Debug.Log("Se cambio el numero de dinero!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's the culprit but it is due to the `Input.anyKeyDown` responding to mouse clicks, not just key inputs. This will clash with your MouseDown function and overwrite your values.